# c# format datetime and decimal without changing the culture

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to display datetime along with decimal value in following format without changing the culture
hour:minute AM/PM month/day/year for example 9:00 pm 05/21/2017 32-45

this is my function

```
public static void FormatDateTime(DateTime date, double temperature)
   {
      string tempDate;
     tempDate = string.Format("Event at {0:t} {0:dd/mm/yy} {1:N2}", date, temperature);
   }
```

Comment: Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: Looks like you have minutes (`mm`) instead of months (`MM`), but hard to tell if that's what you're asking.  I don't see a question or a problem statement here.

Comment: @MattJohnson. my code was not displaying AM / PM. Also date was not in correct format. I don't understand why MM has to be  upper case and dd yy in lower case to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try the code below:**

```
public static void FormatDateTime(DateTime date, double temperature)
{
    string tempDate;
    tempDate = string.Format("Event at {0:hh:mm tt} {0:MM/dd/yyyy} {1:N2}", date, temperature);
}
```

**Result**

- Event at 09:28 AM 05/22/2017 75.00

Answer (score 0):

you can try this line of code to format the date only then you can concatenate the temperature in any format you like

```
date.ToString("hh:mm tt MM/dd/yyyy");
```